# Function that returns an unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to make a function that takes a single string filename input, and returns an unordered_map.  I basically know what to do inside of my function, but I don't know what variable type to make my function in order for me to be able to return an unordered_map.  In order just to be able to write stuff in my function, I just made it an int variable type, but I obviously can't return an unordered_map.  Would really appreciate some help!  I'll attach my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int count_words(string filename);

int main() {

    count_words("trainneg.txt");

    return 0;
}

int count_words(string filename) {

    ifstream ifs(filename);

    string line;
    unordered_map<string, int> word_counter;

    while (getline(ifs, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        string word;
        int count;

            while (getline(iss, word, ' ')) {
                word_counter[word] += 1;
            }

    }

    return word_counter;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you get a whole line, just to put it back into a stream and get words instead? Counting words in one line: `auto r = distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::ifstream(filename)), {})`.

Comment: What's preventing you from using unordered map as a return type?

Comment: Why is it that you "obviously can't return an unordered_map"? I mean, other than that you've declared that you're returning `int`? If you want to change the return type, do it.

Comment: If performance is your concern - no, there won't be a huge copy. Worst case, you get a move construction, which is a few pointers swap. Best case, copy elision: your map will be constructed directly at the call site

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;`!

Comment: @cHao that is the point of my question.  I don't know what to change the type to.  Would love any type of help.  I'm just confused because I have to take only one input, the filename in a string, and then I have to return the unordered_map.  I've spent so much time on this and still can't find a way to make it return the unordered_map.  So frustrating -_-

Comment: @IanHegstrom: Since you're declaring that the return type is `int` (that's what **`int`** `count_words(string filename)` means), you don't then get to return an `unordered_map`. If you want the function to return an `unordered_map` instead, then change your declaration to say so.

Comment: @cHao I understand that.  But wouldn't declaring my function declaration as an unordered_map require 2 inputs?  I was told my function had to strictly take only one input.  EDIT: wow i completely understand now... I guess I didn't have a true understanding of how an unordered_map function worked.  thanks everyone

Comment: @IanHegstrom: It'd probably help you to not think of it as "an unordered_map function". It's just a function. The return type doesn't significantly change anything about the function other than what you'll get back from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it two ways:

- Either you return the `undeordered_map` directly (nothing prevents you from returning it, but you can't return it as if it was an `int` as you did)
- or you pass a pre-existing one to your function

These are slight changes anyway.

Option one, return it directly:

```
unordered_map<string, int> count_words(string filename);

[...]

unordered_map<string, int> count_words(string filename) 
{
    [...]

        // int count; You don't need it, it's unused in your code.

    [...]

    return word_counter;
}
```

Option two, you pass it:

```
void count_words(string filename, unordered_map<string, int> & word_counter);

int main() {

    unordered_map<string, int> word_counter;
    count_words("trainneg.txt", word_counter);

    return 0;
}

void count_words(string filename, unordered_map<string, int> & word_counter) {
    [...]

    word_counter.clear(); // The map is preexisting. We clear it instead of creating it.

    [...]

    // no return statement in that case, that's a void
}
```

---

<sup>**Sidenote**: Oh, viewing the comments I'm realizing this might be a homework assignment, I didn't notice. Should this be the case, don't just take this answer as it is. Try to criticize it, why to chose option 1, why to chose option 2? Depending on how advanced you are, @KABoissonneault is opening interesting doors in his comment for example. Also, why was `count_words()` defined as returning `int` in the first place? If it was given, maybe you should question your approach. If it was your choice, why to wish to return a map in that case? These questions are not to be answered here, they are for you to think about all these things (and maybe to discuss outside this Q&A should this be helpful in any way).</sup>

Comment: Which option is recommended?

Comment: @MrSquid It all depends on your context, on what you are willing to do. There's no generic answer to this question. A good starting point to determine which option to chose would be the lifecycle of that map.